# How to change a commit content after the commit has been pushed to the remote branch?

Tags: git, github, push, git-amend

I need to change a file that i have already pushed but i don't want to do a new commit, so i tried amend. But when I try to push the changes to the remote branch it gives me an error.
Do I need to do a force push or something else ??
I'm the only one working on this project so no one is going to pull this branch(I can use amend).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use force push, but please note that it should be allowed in your branch configuration.

```
git push origin [branch] -f
```

This will basically override the branch. So use it for shared remote branches like master with caution.

Comment: How would i do it if I need to push from a local branch A to a remote branch B git push origin A:B -f ?

Comment: I have never tried to make git push when branch names different. But you are probably right: git push -f A:B

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need to force push, which is fine if your are the only one working on the remote repository.